# DateTime Diff C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm using `DateTime` C#.
I have an XML file with value HOUR, i.e:

```
<MyXML>
    <LastTimeTaskRun>11:50</LastTimeTaskRun>
</MyXML>
```

And i have a task that running each 5 min.
I want to know if the current time and the hour from the xml big then 5 min.
What I'm trying:

```
int hour, min;
DateTime dateTimeXML = DateTime.Now, dateTimeNow;
string [] lastSuccessTime = LastSuccessTime.Split(':');

 Int32.TryParse(lastSuccessTime[0], out hour);
 Int32.TryParse(lastSuccessTime[1], out min);

 dateTimeXML = dateTimeXML.Date + new TimeSpan(hour, min, 0);
 dateTimeNow = DateTime.Now;

 bool isBigThen5Min = (dateTimeNow - dateTimeXML).TotalMinutes > 5;
```

The code is works fine, but i want to know what is the best way (performance) to do that.

Thanks

Comment: *The code is works fine, but i want to know what is the best way (performance) to do that.* Your question would be a better fit for [codereview.se], then.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [CodeReview.SE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `TimeSpan.Parse`. This is designed for what you are trying to do:

```
var span =  TimeSpan.Parse(LastSuccessTime);
```

MSDN article is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx)